# Google does not index my web site pages

Tags: seo, google-search

I changed my web sites' DNS, server and URL format.

So my web site's many links become broken and then I repaired all broken links after a month but during this, Google has deleted all my index and it still does not index my web site although I used a sitemap, meta tags, title and description etc …

What should I do for Google to index my web site?

This is my sitemap: http://yazilimsozluk.com/SiteMap/Index

Answer (score 1):

i think it may works :- https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1
Submit your website for inclusion in Google's index.

Comment: thank you @Purusottam Sahu ...should i add all my url to web masters tools?or just give base domain(YazilimSozluk.com)

Comment: I think you should just add as YazilimSozluk.com